# Trying to create a new column in a data frame using a function in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame, and I would like to create a new column for the data frame in R but I am struggling.
I am a relative beginner and I would be very grateful for some help.

Essentially I am looking to create a new column of AKI stage, based on an individuals peak and baseline creatinine measurements, and whether they have been on renal-replacement therapy (RRT), according to the following criteria:

stage 1: Peak Cr/Baseline Cr = 1.5–1.9  OR  Peak Cr ≥ Baseline Cr + 26.5mmol/l)

stage 2: Peak Cr/Baseline Cr = 2.0–2.9

stage 3: Peak Cr/Baseline Cr ≥ 3   OR  Peak cr ≥353.6mmol/l  OR  Initiation of RRT

My data looks like this, in which I have 3 main variables.

```
head(data)
 Peak.Creatinine.1 baseline.Cr.within.12.months new.RRT
1               421                           82       1
2               659                           98       1
3               569                           89       1
4               533                          113       1
5               533                          212       1
6               396                           65       1
```

I would like to create a new column called "AKI.stage", which returns a number 0,1,2,3 or 4.
Which essentially uses this function:

```
akistage <- function(peak_cr, bl_cr, rrt=0) {
  ratio <- peak_cr / bl_cr
  if (rrt == "1"){return(3)}
  else if (ratio >= 3){return(3)}
  else if (peak_cr > 353.6){return(3)}
  else if (ratio > 2 & ratio <3){return(2)}
  else if (ratio > 1.5 & ratio <2){return(1)}
  else if ((peak_cr >= bl_cr + 26.5)){return(1)}
  else {return (0)}
}
```

The function works well when I test it, but I can't seem to apply it to the dataframe in order to create the new column.
I have attempted this in multiple ways including using apply,mapply,mutate,transform etc but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Here are some of my failed attempts:

```
data2$Peak.Creatinine.1 <- as.numeric(data2$Peak.Creatinine.1)
data2$baseline.Cr.within.12.months <- as.numeric(data2$baseline.Cr.within.12.months)
data2$test <- apply(data2, 1, function(x){
  ratio <- x[1] / x[2]
  peak_cr <- x[1]
  bl_cr <- x[2]
  rrt <- x[3]
  if (rrt == "1"){return(3)}
  else if (ratio >= 3){return(3)}
  else if (peak_cr > 353.6){return(3)}
  else if (ratio > 2 & ratio <3){return(2)}
  else if (ratio > 1.5 & ratio <2){return(1)}
  else if ((peak_cr >= bl_cr + 26.5)){return(1)}
  else {return (0)}
})
```

But this returns the following error message, despite being of class numerical:

```
Error in x[1]/x[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Another attempt:

```
data2 %>% 
  mutate(test = 
           akistage(Peak.Creatinine.1,baseline.Cr.within.12.months,new.RRT))
```

Returns

```
Warning message:
In if (rrt == "1") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have attempted it in lots of other ways, and I'm not sure why it's not working.
It does not seem very difficult to do, I would be extremely grateful if someone could come up with a solution!

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: In stage 3, what do you mean by the last condition, `OR Initiation of RRT`?

Comment: Hi Paul! Could you add an example of the output you would like? I think I have the solution for you, just want to make sure it produces what you want.

Comment: Try using `sapply()` or `lapply()`, though I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following vectorized function does what the question describes. It uses index vectors to assign the return values to a previously created vector `AKI.stage`.

```
akistage <- function(peak_cr, bl_cr, rrt = 0) {
  AKI.stage <- numeric(length(peak_cr))
  ratio <- peak_cr / bl_cr
  rrt1 <- rrt == 1
  i <- findInterval(ratio, c(0, 1.5, 2, 3, Inf))
  AKI.stage[rrt1 | i == 4 | peak_cr > 353.6] <- 3
  AKI.stage[!rrt1 & i == 3] <- 2
  AKI.stage[!rrt1 & i == 2] <- 1
  AKI.stage[!rrt1 & i == 1 & peak_cr >= bl_cr + 26.5] <- 1
  AKI.stage
}


data %>% 
  mutate(test = akistage(Peak.Creatinine.1,baseline.Cr.within.12.months,new.RRT))
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you different solutions to add a new colum to a `data.frame` using only base R :

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = rep(0, 100), v2 = seq(1, 100))
v3 <- rep(0, 100)

# first way with a $
df$v3 <- v3

# second way with cbind
df <- cbind(df, v3)

# third way
df[, 3] <- 3
```

**EDIT 1**

Your problem is coming from the fact that your third column is a `factor` so when you use `apply` it transforms all your data into character. The right way to do what you want is :

```
sapply(1:nrow(data2), function(i, df){
  x <- df[i,]
  ratio <- x[1] / x[2]
  peak_cr <- x[1]
  bl_cr <- x[2]
  rrt <- x[3]
  if (rrt == "1"){return(3)}
  else if (ratio >= 3){return(3)}
  else if (peak_cr > 353.6){return(3)}
  else if (ratio > 2 & ratio <3){return(2)}
  else if (ratio > 1.5 & ratio <2){return(1)}
  else if ((peak_cr >= bl_cr + 26.5)){return(1)}
  else {return (0)}
}, df = data2)
```